# Append np array with a determined value. Data isn't appending to list when using np.append

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am developing a code to use data from a light sensor to determine the gradient of an experiment.
Part of the code requires appending 2 arrays (systemtime and volume total). The relevant part of my code reads:

```
systemtime = np.array([])
volumetotal = np.array([])
volume = 0
...
while True:
    a = time()
    ...
       np.append(systemtime , a)
     ...
       volume = volume + added
       np.append(volumetotal,volume)
       if added == 0:
           break       
ser.close()
print (systemtime)
time = systemtime-systemtime[0]
```

When printing system time the console shows and empty list [], therefore the final line of code doesn't work.
How can I successfully append the lists? (... used to remove unnecessary bits of code)

Comment: `np.append` is not a list append clone.  Don't use as such.  Better yet, don't use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you assign the extension of your *systemtime* or *volumetotal* list to a variable.

```
systemtime = np.array([])
volumetotal = np.array([])
volume = 0
...
while True:
    a = time()
    ...
       systemtime = np.append(systemtime, a)
     ...
       volume = volume + added
       volumetotal = np.append(volumetotal, volume)
       if added == 0:
           break       
ser.close()
print (systemtime)
time = systemtime-systemtime[0]
```

Without this, your use of the *append* method from *numpy* has no effect: you only create locally (so on this single line) the list you want to create, without giving you the possibility to access it afterwards.

Comment: Awesome Samuel, thank you very much. I'll try this out tomorrow when i'm back at work.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays do nothing for you here.

```
systemtime = []
volumetotal = []
volume = 0
...
while True:
    a = time()
    ...
       systemtime.append(a)
     ...
       volume = volume + added
       volumetotal.append(volume)
       if added == 0:
           break       
ser.close()
print (systemtime)
time = [t-systemtime[0] for t in systemtime]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am writing the code using both for loops and using NumPy arrays as a way to introduce students to the concept of arrays. I guess it's probably not the most ideal way to do it but we only have 1 coding based practical a semester so they have to cover a lot of bases

Comment: Unfortunately, treating numpy arrays as though they were just lists is error prone and slow.  Also the students need to learn basic programming skills, like reading the documentation, and debugging.  We see too many SO where the user has borrowed some code, and tries to use it without understanding any of the basics - of Python, `numpy` or the package itself.  The moment they deviate from the instructions, or try to use their own data, they run into problems.  And the only 'debugging' they do is 'search the web' or ask for SO help.